# load all the resources before load page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my question

I a have one webpage  with lot of images including small and big resolutions 
both in HTML and CSS I used those images (eg: as background image in CSS classes )

Now I need to load all my images before loading my site I tried to search in google I got many suggestions but in those they are using id class and ect... but I need to load all my images regardless of any class or id.

I need some thing like this 
http://www.entheosweb.com/tutorials/css/preloader/Demo.html

help will be really appreciated

thank you...

Answer (score 1):

All you need is `onload` event on the `body` tag. It indicates that the page has loaded completely. You need to show some animation covering the whole page until the page is loaded just as mentioned in the link you provided.

**Displaying the loader**

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    // Display the loader logic
}
```

**Hiding the loader**

```
function hideLoader(){
    // Hide the loader
}

<body onload="hideLoader()">
```